# Stringbuilder not written to HttpContext.Current.Response.Write in some conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looping through two input controls of type file with this function.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
    int numFiles = hfc.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        string FilePath = hpf.FileName;
        CreateProgress(FilePath, i + 1, numFiles);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

At this stage I am doing nothing with the files, I just want to prove that after uploading each file I can write something to the browser to let the user know the files are being uploaded. The function CreateProgress is this:

```
public void CreateProgress(string FilePath, int i, int numFiles)

{
    StringBuilder sbProgress = new StringBuilder();
    string strTableId = "mainTable" + i;
    sbProgress.Append("<html><head><link rel=\"StyleSheet\" href=\"stylesheet/StyleSheet1.css\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body>");
    sbProgress.Append("<table id=\"" + strTableId + "\" border=\"0\">");
    sbProgress.Append("<tr>"); 
    sbProgress.Append("<td>");
    sbProgress.Append("<p class=\"filey\">Uploading " + FilePath + " ..... file " + i.ToString() + " of " + numFiles.ToString() + "</p>");
    sbProgress.Append("</td>");
    sbProgress.Append("<td style=\"display:none\">");
    sbProgress.Append("</td>");
    sbProgress.Append("</tr>");
    sbProgress.Append("</table>");
    sbProgress.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sbProgress.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

The code as above works perfectly every time. I click to upload the files and on the screen it shows 'Uploading SomeFile.txt ... file 1 of 2' for 2 seconds and then 'Uploading SomeOtherFile.txt ... file 2 of 2' for 2 seconds.

But, you'll see in the code building the StringBuilder that I am constructing a table with one row and two cells. I don't need or use the second cell in the row but if I delete it by commenting out three lines like this ...

```
    public void CreateProgress(string FilePath, int i, int numFiles)

{
    StringBuilder sbProgress = new StringBuilder();
    string strTableId = "mainTable" + i;
    sbProgress.Append("<html><head><link rel=\"StyleSheet\" href=\"stylesheet/StyleSheet1.css\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body>");
    sbProgress.Append("<table id=\"" + strTableId + "\" border=\"0\">");
    sbProgress.Append("<tr>"); 
    sbProgress.Append("<td>");
    sbProgress.Append("<p class=\"filey\">Uploading " + FilePath + " ..... file " + i.ToString() + " of " + numFiles.ToString() + "</p>");
    //sbProgress.Append("</td>");
    //sbProgress.Append("<td style=\"display:none\">");
    //sbProgress.Append("</td>");
    sbProgress.Append("</tr>");
    sbProgress.Append("</table>");
    sbProgress.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sbProgress.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

... then, when the Upload button is clicked - nothing happens at first, then the second message shows on the screen (Uploading file 2 of 2). Why on earth does commenting out three lines so that the second cell in the row is not created cause it to stop working properly?

In fact, if I leave the 3 lines in and remove the 'style="display:none"' from the td tag - it does not work properly. Put the style="display:none" back in and it works fine.

In actual fact I don't want to really create a table at all. I have tried removing the lot and simply doing this:

```
    StringBuilder sbProgress = new StringBuilder();
    sbProgress.Append("<html><head><link rel=\"StyleSheet\" href=\"stylesheet/StyleSheet1.css\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body>");
    sbProgress.Append("<p class=\"filey\">Uploading " + FilePath + " ..... file " + i.ToString() + " of " + numFiles.ToString() + "</p>");
    sbProgress.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sbProgress.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

but this does not work either. The first message 'Uploading file 1 of 2' does not appear, but the second one ('Uploading file 2 of 2') does appear.

Any ideas? I'm thinking of becoming a taxi driver.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're working against the request/response nature of HTTP here. You'd do better if you'd generate some sort of "operation identifier" at the initial request, and serve that to the client. Then write some Javascript to poll the progress of the operation, passing in the operation identifier each time. That way you can have a series of *complete* request/response pairs, rather than relying on how the browser handles a response which hasn't completed yet.

(You could use long-polling instead of just regular timed polling, only returning when each part is complete, but you'd still have the same basic multi-request setup.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand ... How would I generate an 'operation identifier' at the beginning of the request and how do you get javascript to poll something going on on the server? I only want to write to the screen after each file is uploaded - if I poll how will the javascript function know what is going on?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse: The identifier can just be a random GUID... anything that you remember on the server and pass to the client. Getting Javascript to poll should be straightforward - just make an AJAX request every two seconds, passing the identifier; the server needs to keep track of what's going on in each long-running operation, so it can give the appropriate status.

Answer (score 0):

You actually created a malformed markup

```
//sbProgress.Append("</td>");
//sbProgress.Append("<td style=\"display:none\">");
//sbProgress.Append("</td>");
```

You should have commented the last two lines. The first line should be the closing tag of the  above it.

should have been

```
sbProgress.Append("<p class=\"filey\">Uploading " + FilePath + " ..... file " + i.ToString() + " of " + numFiles.ToString() + "</p>");
sbProgress.Append("</td>");
//sbProgress.Append("<td style=\"display:none\">");
//sbProgress.Append("</td>");
sbProgress.Append("</tr>");
```

Comment: That was a typo copying the code to here. In fact when testing I have been commenting out those two lines. Comment them out and the first message does not get written to the screen. Comment them back in and it does. Weird how adding in a cell you don't need makes it work. It is very strange.